# Cannot sort array of Javascript objects received through an angular REST call

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm facing a rather odd problem with sorting an array of Javascript objects.
I tried sorting some dummy data and it works. For some reason I can't sort it if I get that object through an angular REST call.

The message looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "IIB",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "some_random_id",
            "name": "Broker2",
            "size": 1627,
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "some_random_id",
            "name": "Broker1",
            "size": 203,
            "children": []
        }
     ]
}
```

What I want to do is to sort the first level `children` array based on the `name` attribute.

I tried using the `sort()` method to do it but for some reason it doesn't work in this case:

```
       // restangular REST call to get that message as "data"
       INode.one('topology').get().then(function(data) {

            // trying to sort the children array
            data.children = data.children.sort(function(a, b) {
                if (a.name > b.name) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (a.name < b.name) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 0;
            })
            console.log(data.children);

        });
```

Now if I run that code my children array is not affected at all and it comes randomised every time. I also tried to pass the reference to another variable and work with that, but it still doesn't work.

It works if I copy and paste the actual JSON object straight into the source and then sort that one out.

It also works if I use jQuery's ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "same_url_angular_is_using",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        data.children = data.children.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a.name > b.name) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (a.name < b.name) {
                return -1;
            }
            // a must be equal to b
            return 0;
        });

        console.log(data.children);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the way angular is parsing the JSON message.

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: I tried you code in browser's console and it works. ( input was your example )

Comment: inspect `data` in your developer tools and make sure it's what you expect it to be

Comment: Note that `.sort()` modifies the array it is called on in place, so you don't need to assign the result back to the same variable/property. You don't get any errors or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Angular copy API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)
and copy the data to a variable and try to apply sort function to the newly copied variable. It should work.

Comment: Tried it but I still get the array in a random order: `var newVar = angular.copy(data);`

Comment: Ok, I investigated it a bit more and apparently the order is randomised if I assign the newVar to the scope later in the code. if I assign it like this `$scope.topology = angular.copy(newVar)' then the `console.log` displays it properly. I don't know how that's possible because I have the `console.log` before the `$scope` assignment ... so confused about this

Comment: thats interesting.. If you can post fiddler link that would help me to investigate better. But in Angular never try to manipulate data object received. Instead copy it to a scoped variable. Angular kinda creates as immutable property. **Hope something helped you!**

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the problem in a fiddle. Something else in my application must be doing something funny. I'll get back to you if I find more clues about this. For some reason if I assign the sorted variable to the $scope and then `console.log` that scope right after, the $scope is randomised...

Comment: Sure , i am happy to help you. Vote up the answer so that it can help if somebody is facing similar problem.